# Need assistance with virtual-desktop annoyances

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, virtual-desktop

I have some virtual-desktop-related questions.

What's the keyboard shortcut to switch between Desktop 1, 2, and 3 when in Win+Tab mode?

[image]

Neither the tab nor the arrow keys work.

Why does Win+Tab show the history, when it's been disabled?

[image]

[image]

Are there a way to force a full-screen, RDC session to act like a VD?  You can use Alt+Tab and Win+Tab to access it, but you can't use either to navigate from it.

Comment: I would have answered your last question, but it's not clear, so I answered the questions I knew.  You would have to be more explicitly clear on what your trying to achieve with the last question. My current assumption is that VD, stands for Virtual Desktop, and thus my answer would simply be that *a Remote Connection isn't a virtual desktop and there is no way to change that fact.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the keyboard shortcut to switch between Desktop 1, 2, and 3 when in Win+Tab mode?

The correct keyboard shortcut is `Windows Key + Ctrl + Left Arrow` and `Windows Key + Ctrl + Right Arrow`

> Why does Win+Tab show the history, when it's been disabled?

You have only disabled suggestions based on your activity history. You need to disable `Store my activity history on this device`, `Send my activity history to Microsoft`, and `Show activities from accounts` within Activity history instead.